# Can I shake a charge to illuminate my surroundings?

Tags: electromagnetism, visible-light, electromagnetic-radiation, charge, acceleration

If I put charge on the tip of a rod and shake it back and forth at the right frequency, can I illuminate my surroundings?

According to my understanding of Maxwell equations this would create EM waves that would provided the right frequency to be be registered as light.

Comment: I've removed a number of comments that were attempting to answer the question and/or responses to them. Please keep in mind that comments should be used for suggesting improvements and requesting clarification on the question, not for answering.

Answer (score 3):

By shaking your wand, you would produce electromagnetic waves with the same frequency as your wand-shaking. The waves thus produced would be extremely weak ultra, ultra, ultra-low frequency radio waves which your eyes are not sensitive to.

So you would still be in the dark.

Answer (score 2):

I think the spirit of your question is "If I *somehow* manage to shake a charge at the right frequency, will it emit visible light?". In this case the answer is yes: this is exactly what [free electron laser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_electron_laser) does. But instead of having an object holding and shaking the charge, the charge itself is passed through an alternating-polarity magnet and thus oscillates, emitting [synchrotron radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchrotron_radiation).